# Trying to send a message to a recently created Text Channel using discord.py

Tags: discord.py

The code in question below works flawlesly, it creates a channel and gives it a description.
But i can't figure out how to proceed from here and have it send a message to this channel right after creation, any help would be appreciated.

```py
        # Text Channel
    settings = utils.get_serv_settings(guild)
    if 'text_channels' in settings and settings['text_channels'] and is_gold(guild):
        try:
            r = await guild.create_role(name="vc {}".format(c.id))
        except discord.errors.Forbidden:
            return c
        await creator.add_roles(r)
        overwrites = {
            guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
            r: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        }
        if 'stct' in settings:
            showto_r = guild.get_role(settings['stct'])
            if showto_r:
                overwrites[showto_r] = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
        tc = await guild.create_text_channel(
            utils.nice_cname(settings['text_channel_name']) if 'text_channel_name' in settings else "voice context",
            category=primary.category,
            overwrites=overwrites,
            topic=("<a:arrowg:972810849783808040> Type '!vc help | This channel is only visible to members of your voice channel, "
                   "It will be deleted when everyone leaves. VC ID: {}".format(c.id)))
        settings = utils.get_serv_settings(guild)
        settings['auto_channels'][primary.id]['secondaries'][c.id]['tc'] = tc.id
        settings['auto_channels'][primary.id]['secondaries'][c.id]['tcr'] = r.id
        utils.set_serv_settings(guild, settings)
    if creator in c.members:
        unlock_channel_request(c)
    else:
        log("{}  Still trying to move {}".format(str(c.id)[-4:], creator.display_name), guild)
        lock_channel_request(c, 20)
        lock_user_request(creator, 20)
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a message to the channel your just created.

```py
channel = await guild.create_text_channel(*args) # this returns the channel that was created so u can use it to send the message
await channel.send("message")
```

Comment: You should `await channel.send()`

Comment: ahh sorry. Thanks for pointing that out